# Как реализовать эффект затемнения изображения с двумя кнопками?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Уважаемые профи!
Прошу помощи в реализации следующего эффекта.

[image: Фрагмент]

Смог сделать всё, кроме работающих кнопок "лупа" и "ссылка".

Мой фрагмент кода:

```js
$('.projects-post').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).find('.projects-post__arrow>img').attr('src', '../img/projects/arrow-activ.png');
  $(this).find('.projects-post-img').css('background-color', '#362f2d');
  $(this).find('.projects-post-text').css('background-color', '#362f2d');
});
$('.projects-post').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).find('.projects-post__arrow>img').attr('src', '../img/projects/arrow.png');
  $(this).find('.projects-post-img').css('background-color', '#fbfaf8');
  $(this).find('.projects-post-text').css('background-color', '#fbfaf8');
});
```

```css
.projects-post {
  background-color: #fbfaf8;
}

.projects-post-img {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.projects-post-img a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.projects-post-img a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
}

.projects-post-img a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url("../img/projects/lupa.png") center no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.projects-post-img a:hover:before,
.projects-post-img a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.projects-post__arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 30px;
}

.projects-post-text {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.projects-post-text__title {
  color: #c7b299;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.projects-post-text__subtitle {
  color: #d1d1d1;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-4 projects-post webdesign justify-content-center mb-4">
  <div class="projects-post-img text-center p-2 w-100">
    <a href="img/projects/photo1.jpg">
      <img class="w-100 h-100" src="img/projects/photo-1.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
    <div class="projects-post__arrow">
      <img src="img/projects/arrow.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="projects-post-text pl-4">
    <h5 class="projects-post-text__title">Claritas Etiam Processus</h5>
    <small class="projects-post-text__subtitle">Photography, Nature</small>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 projects-post webdesign justify-content-center mb-4">
  <div class="projects-post-img text-center p-2 w-100">
    <a href="img/projects/photo2.jpg">
      <img class="w-100 h-100" src="img/projects/photo-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
    <div class="projects-post__arrow">
      <img src="img/projects/arrow.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="projects-post-text pl-4">
    <h5 class="projects-post-text__title">Quam Nutamus Farum</h5>
    <small class="projects-post-text__subtitle">Graphic Design, Mock-Up</small>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 projects-post mobile justify-content-center mb-4">
  <div class="projects-post-img text-center p-2 w-100">
    <a href="img/projects/photo3.jpg">
      <img class="w-100 h-100" src="img/projects/photo-3.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="projects-post__arrow">
      <img src="img/projects/arrow.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="projects-post-text pl-4">
    <h5 class="projects-post-text__title">Usus Legentis Videntur</h5>
    <small class="projects-post-text__subtitle">Photography, Holiday</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Я так понял вом нужно использовать CSS3 Transitions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907079/css3-transition-fade-out-effect

Comment: Мне кажется это не совсем то, что я хотел. Мне нужно реализовать следующее: при наведении на картинку она меняются цвета и тому подобное, но самое главное затемняется картинка и на на ней появляются две иконки "поделиться ссылкой" и "лупа" . Вопрос у меня как к этим иконкам прикрутить ссылки (например "лупа" откроет большое изображение).

Comment: Либо я что-то не догнал..

Comment: Сделайте эти ссылки невидимыми, а потом транзишином при наведении показывайте их

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не по вашему примеру сделал но показал механизм как такое реализуется

Создаём блок в котором находится всё то что надо скрыть и  показываем при событии hover

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.post_hidden {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  padding: 20px;
  background: #222;
  transition: 0.34s linear;
}

.post_hidden h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fbfbfb;
}

.post_hidden p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fbfbfb;
}

.post_hidden p {
  width: 200px;
}

.preview {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.34s linear;
}

.item {
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 140px;
}

.item a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: #fbfbfb;
}

.items:hover .wrapper {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.items:hover .post_hidden {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="items">
  <div class="preview">
    <img src="https://buyoncdn.ru/product/1890406454/product_mainpage/1537834/fly-ezzy-trendy-3-temno-seryy.jpg" alt="" width="220px">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-chain-broken" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="post_hidden">
      <h3>post name</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, eaque?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это как раз то, что мне нужно! Сейчас разберусь, чтобы положить на свой код. Низкий Вам поклон!